# Hibernate: SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update AND BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

Tags: java, oracle, hibernate, maven, oracle11g

I follow this tutorial in mkyong.com: http://www.mkyong.com/hibernate/maven-3-hibernate-3-6-oracle-11g-example-xml-mapping/

But when I run file App.java, it show the following log:

```
Maven + Hibernate + Oracle
SLF4J: Failed to load class "org.slf4j.impl.StaticLoggerBinder".
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See http://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#StaticLoggerBinder for further details.
Hibernate: insert into DB11G.DBUSER (USERNAME, CREATED_BY, CREATED_DATE, USER_ID) values (?, ?, ?, ?)
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: Could not execute JDBC batch update
    at org.hibernate.exception.SQLStateConverter.convert(SQLStateConverter.java:92)
    at org.hibernate.exception.JDBCExceptionHelper.convert(JDBCExceptionHelper.java:66)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:268)
    at org.hibernate.engine.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:184)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:321)
    at org.hibernate.event.def.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:51)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1216)
    at org.hibernate.impl.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:383)
    at org.hibernate.transaction.JDBCTransaction.commit(JDBCTransaction.java:133)
    at com.mkyong.App.main(App.java:22)
Caused by: java.sql.BatchUpdateException: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist

    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OraclePreparedStatement.executeBatch(OraclePreparedStatement.java:10070)
    at oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleStatementWrapper.executeBatch(OracleStatementWrapper.java:213)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.BatchingBatcher.doExecuteBatch(BatchingBatcher.java:70)
    at org.hibernate.jdbc.AbstractBatcher.executeBatch(AbstractBatcher.java:268)
    ... 8 more
```

I even download sample code and import into Eclipse but it still show log.

Note: I changed SID and password by following:

```
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class">oracle.jdbc.driver.OracleDriver</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.url">jdbc:oracle:thin:@127.0.0.1:1521:DB11G</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.username">mkyong</property>
        <property name="hibernate.connection.password">mkyong123</property>
        <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.Oracle10gDialect</property>
        <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DB11G</property>
        <property name="show_sql">true</property>
        <mapping resource="com/mkyong/user/DBUser.hbm.xml"></mapping>
    </session-factory>
</hibernate-configuration>
```

Please help me!Thanks you.

Comment: You are connecting to `username">mkyong</property>` schema, but trying to create a table in aonther schema `hibernate.default_schema">DB11G</property>`. Do these both schemas (users) exist on Oracle ? It would be easier to use only one schema, either `mykong` or `db11g`, and delete `default_schema` tag from the configuration. Otherwise you need to grant `select/insert/delete` privileges to Oracle user `mykong` on all tables in `DB11g` schema.

Comment: Looks more like a configuration issue, check hibernate configuration again.

Comment: @kordirko I don't get your point when you call "mkyong" in        username">mkyong</property> is a schema, it's an username in schema         DB11G

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @kordirko I don't get your point when you call "mkyong" in
>   username">mkyong is a schema, it's an username in schema
>   DB11G

On Oracle a user is equivalent to a schema.  See a definition:
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14220/schema.htm#i22627

> A schema is a collection of logical structures of data, or schema
>   objects. A schema is owned by a database user and **has the same name as
>   that user**. Each user owns a single schema.

The user `mykong` has a shema named `mykong`. The user `DB11G` has a schema named `DB11G`. `mykong` is a name of both the user and the schema. The same applies to `DB11G`.

---

Your configuration contains the following entries:

```
<property name="hibernate.connection.username">mkyong</property>
<property name="hibernate.connection.password">mkyong123</property>
```

This means, that hibernate connects to the Oracle database as an user named `mkyong`, to a schema named `mykong`.
If you connect as `mykong` to the database, a schema named `mykong` is a default schema for this user. If you issue a query `SELECT * FROM tablename`, the database is looking, by default, for a table named `tablename` in a schema of logged user.
If you are logged as a user `mykong`, and you want to access a table of other user (in his schema) - say `DB11G`, then you must prepend a table name with a schema name, like this: `SELECT * FROM DB11G.tablename`.
But this will work only if user `DB11G` (or system) granted privileges on this table to user `mykong` !

---

Your confoiguration contains also this entry:

```
 <property name="hibernate.default_schema">DB11G</property>
```

A meaning of this option is explained here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/core.old/reference/en/html/configuration-optional.html

> **hibernate.default_schema**  
>   Qualify unqualified table names with the
>   given schema/tablespace in generated SQL. eg. SCHEMA_NAME

The above means, that Hibernate will prepend all obiects referenced by all queries with a prefix: `DB11G.`- this is a name of schema `DB11G`, and also a name of user `DB11G` that owns this schema. That is - Hibernate is looking for all tables in a schema `DB11G`, not in a schema of `mykong`, which is actually loggeg in.
You can do one of the following:

1. Login as user `DB11G`, not as `mykong` ==> use: `<property name="hibernate.connection.username">DB11G</property>`
2. Remove this line from the configuration: `<property name="hibernate.default_schema">DB11G</property>`
3. Or grant appriopriate privileges (select, insert, update) to user `mykong` on all tables on the schema `DB11G`